# Visual Studio 2013 Not Opening *.cshtml files

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013

I cannot figure out why Visual Studio is not opening CSHTML files.  The error message I get this:

> The document cannot be opened.  It has been renamed, deleted or moved.

The file exists.  I can change the extension to .html and open the file no problem.  If I change the extension back to .cshtml with the file still open it lets me modify it.  If I close the file and try to open it again I get the above message.  Every other file type will open except .cshtml.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

**** UPDATE ****

Figured out that it has something to do with the HTML Editor used by default for .cshtml files. If I right click, open with... and select a different editor, it will open but I lose all intellisense and it doesn't recognize any of the razor syntax.  Installing Update 4 for VS 2013 to see if that works.

Comment: restart the VS and look at the files listed. Is there a caution tag near them?

Comment: I've restarted VS multiple times.  Deleted the *.suo file and restarted.  Removed and readded TFS bindings.  There are no caution tags or any kind of warning/error.  Project builds and runs fine.

Comment: Building or running are separate from View related files. let me to think ...

Comment: Opened solution on a different machine and everything works fine.  No issues opening files at all.

Comment: Just finished repairing the installation and that didn't work either.

Comment: I told that VS repair doesn't take effect. what happen if you recreate a project?

Comment: Had same issue.  Get to reinstall the OS on Monday.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: am having the same issue :-( weird. Deleting project and solution .suo files doesn't do anything, same as you I can right-click and open with a different editor. Going to install Update 4 this afternoon, will let you know if that helps...

Comment: @wallismark Installing Update 4 did nothing for my problem.  I wound up reinstalling the OS to fix it.  It was a pain, but wound up saving time in the long run.

Comment: only just got around to it...Installing Update 4 worked for me :-)

Comment: Did you have Xamarin installed?  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26850 I had the same issue, and it appears related.  If it is due to Xamarin, VS Update 4 should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your try, it seems the Application (VS 2013) haven't granted necessary file operation permission on disk (this could be related to IDE files or project files). This could occur by a corrupted operating system.

**Solution:**
Check Directory permission manually **OR** Try to reinstall OS and then VS (reinstalling the VS itself doesn't take effect in many cases).

Comment: I don't believe this would work because other projects will open CSHTML files.  It has to be a solution/project problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just Install Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Xamarin studio and Xamarin for visual studio. Once I uninstalled Xamarin, the problem was solved!
Another thing I tried before removing Xamarin was I right click on .cshtml file and choose "Open with..." and then select "Source Code (Text) Editor". For me in this case i had intellisense.
Hope this helps a friend.

Comment: Thank you for your response Ahmad.  I wound up having to uninstall Visual Studio then reinstall.  Not sure if there was a better way to fix the problem or not, but I couldn't afford to waste more time researching.

Thanks again!